# Reference subnet id in creating ec2 instance - terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to create an EC2 instance using Terraform in a custom VPC.
In the EC2 aws_instance resource, for subnet id, I had to provide as:
`subnet_id         =  "${aws_subnet.test-publicsubnet.id}"`

It did not work when I just mentioned as
`subnet_id         =  aws_subnet.test-publicsubnet.id`

It threw the below error:

```txt
Error: creating EC2 Instance: InvalidSubnetID.NotFound: 
The subnet ID 'aws_subnet.test-publicsubnet.id' does not exist
status code: 400, request id: 517f15ae-3b79-45bb-a35a-04928e704a4d
```

What is the difference between these two definitions?

For vpc id, it is able to pick up, vpc_id = aws_vpc.testvpc.id

My terraform version is v0.13.7
provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v4.16.0

Comment: "It did not work " is not specific. What exactly is happening? Any errors? What TF version do you use?

Comment: modified my question

Comment: could you post the code of the vpc/subnet part?

Answer (score 3):

The error indicates that you used

```
subnet_id = "aws_subnet.test-publicsubnet.id"
```

not as you clame

```
subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.test-publicsubnet.id}"
```

If you did as you clam it would also work. `"${aws_subnet.test-publicsubnet.id}"` is an old  TF 0.11 style. These days you should use:

```
subnet_id = aws_subnet.test-publicsubnet.id
```